# Android - Test for beginning of new line in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, space

In my app, there's a recycler view with items that have titles. Item width and title style is well-defined.  In at least one case, there's a word in a title that is exactly the width of the item.  In this case, the space that follows the word (the word is not the last word in the title) appears at the beginning of the next line in the title.  How would I remove the space in this case?

The below image is a snapshot of the left side of the `TextView`.  The word on the second line is exactly the same size as the width of the `TextView`, so the space is placed on the next line. I would like to remove this space.

[Image of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJlq2.png)

Comment: show your output please, screenshot alongwith xml code

Comment: I can't do this for legal reasons. The scenario should be clear, and the xml is irrelevant.

Comment: It's hard to understand, what your actual problem is. Can you post at least a screenshot?